# Convergence rate of statistical estimator

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, concentration-of-measure

Let's say we have a series of coin flips where there is some unknown bias $p$.

How fast does our estimate of the bias converge to $p$?

**An approach: concentration of measure**

A typical estimate for $p$ after $n$ samples would be $\pi_n = \frac{\#heads}{1- \#tails}$. We can then consider the difference
$$D_n = |\pi_n - p|$$
which we expect to go to $0$ as the number of samples increases.
The Markov inequality gives
$$P(D_n \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \mathbb{E}[D_n].$$

Then $\mathbb{E}[D_n] = |\mathbb{E}[\pi_n] - p| = 0$, which isn't helpful.

**Another approach: Bayesian**

In this case the posterior is a Beta$(a,b)$ where $a= a_0 + \#heads$, $b= b_0 + \#tails$, and Beta$(a_0,b_0)$ is the prior on $\pi$.

I think it would be true that Beta$(a,b) \rightarrow \delta(p)$ where $\delta(p)$ is the true distribution of the bias. I guess this convergence could be measured with some distance measure on distributions, like KL divergence or Wasserstein distance. But how would one prove this goes to $0$? And how would we know the rate?